# How to create a new partitioning table on SD card from the command line ?

Tags: command-line, partition, dd, sd-card

I have tried to mount a SD card on Linux Mint, I have found the right device file and tried: mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /mnt/zauberportal ,but it failed and I tried some variations like different types of file systems after the -t option.

Now, I read, that it is quiet possible that it is because of a badly written partition table, the suggestion was to erase the whole partition table by filling the first 512 bytes of the SD card with zeros: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1, than I should create a partitioning table using a program called gparted, but it did not work.

Is it possible to create a new partitioning table from the command line ?

Comment: "It failed" and "it did not work" provide no useful information. Please read [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)...

Comment: Where did you get "the suggestion" from? Did that include making a backup of the SD? Any reason why to use `gparted` (I only use that for my drives > 2TB)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *possibly* * remove **everything** then you can do your `dd` command; however, you'll still need to create a partition table.

**NOTE I'm going to use /dev/sdb because that is what you have in your original question**

I recommend `fdisk`. So you would do something like the following:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
Command (m for help): n
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (starting-ending, default starting): starting
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (starting-ending, default ending): ending
Command (m for help): w
```

You will then need to format the partition using `mkfs`. If you're only going to use your SD Card in a linux box then use ext3 or ext4:

```
# mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

Otherwise, you're probably safer off with ntfs (check with what you're going to insert the card into):

```
# mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

Once that's done, you can then mount it:

```
# mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

When you're finished, make sure you unmount it:

```
# umount /mnt
```

*All of the data will still be there, but for most end users this means it's as good as gone without a partition table.

Comment: this answer, while correct back in the day, is very outdated now... since all kernels give sd cards the device path /dev/mmcblk0 for the first one, and 1...etc...etc... if you have multiple readers and cards inserted.

further the partitions are numbered, so partition one on your first memory card is:
/dev/mmcblk0p1
/dev/mmcblk0p2 #if you have a second
etc, etc. This may help people.

Answer (score 3):

"fdisk" and "parted" are command line commands to deal with disk partition tables. You may try with them.